# Make EntityManager serializable

Tags: java, eclipse, serialization, glassfish

I have a JavaBean that contains a reference to an EntityManager:

```
@Stateless(name = "mazeBean", mappedName = "mazes")
@Remote @Local
public class MazeBean
{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "mazeEJB")
    private EntityManager em;
```

and it works fine from my web application. I am now developing an ApplicationClient project that uses the same Bean but I am getting an error:

```
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM: WARNING: 00100006: Class beans.__EJB31_Generated__MazeBean__Intf____Bean__ is not Serializable  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 6 completed: Maybe
```

I have researched this a bit and the information I am finding is that the EntityManager may be the cause of the serilization problem. The EntityManager is the only attribute in the class. I have found that all attributes need to be serilizable and EntityManager isn't. I do create other method local objects in the Bean but I haven't called any of them at the point of this error and I expect they would be built on the client anyway.

Firstly; Am I diagnosing this correctly? and if so how do I get around it?

Eclipse Kepler, GF4, MySql 5.5.31, EclipseLink 2.5

Comment: You cannot serialize your `PersistenceContext`. This would imply that you could for example send your `MazeBean` to another machine and access the same database. However, since `EntityManager` is an interface you could implement it yourself and make this implementation serialzable. All calls would then be delegated to the actual `EntityManager`. However, you might just redesign your `MazeBean` instead what is most likely the cleaner solution.

Comment: By redesign do you mean  create interfaces?

Comment: Well I have now created a remote interface and can call the methods I need from the client. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Should have written this as an answer in the first place. Feel free to mark my answer to resolve this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot serialize your `PersistenceContext`. This would imply that you could for example send your `MazeBean` to another machine and access the same database. However, since `EntityManager` is an interface you could implement it yourself and make this implementation serializable. All calls would then be delegated to the actual `EntityManager`. However, you might just redesign your `MazeBean` instead what is most likely the cleaner solution.